# Unable to update my user interface in Android as I update my Mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am working on an e-commerce app.

I am using mysql database from siteground and retrieving data using Volley class. The problem is as I am filling any new data in my table, it should also reflect in my fragment as I re-open my fragment, but it is not happening.

I have to uninstall my app and then re-run the android code and then I can see the data updated in my recycler view. I am using String request class in to retrieve data. I don't know what is the problem; is it something that I am not able to close the fragment properly and it is loading the previous data until I don't uninstall it?

This is my fragment.

```
public class Fragment_Women_Apparels extends Fragment {

private View v;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

ArrayList<String> id1,name,brand,gender,discount,desc,sellprice,markprice,rating,type,size,category,length,
                    image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,shop,color,stock,material;

//5cbytcuv57x4

ProgressBar progressBar;
Animation animation;

public Fragment_Women_Apparels() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_women__apparels_, container, false);

    progressBar=v.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.rotate);
    progressBar.startAnimation(animation);

    id1=new ArrayList<>();
    name=new ArrayList<>();
    brand=new ArrayList<>();
    gender=new ArrayList<>();
    discount=new ArrayList<>();
    desc=new ArrayList<>();
    sellprice=new ArrayList<>();
    markprice=new ArrayList<>();
    rating=new ArrayList<>();
    type=new ArrayList<>();
    size=new ArrayList<>();
    category=new ArrayList<>();
    length=new ArrayList<>();
    image1=new ArrayList<>();
    image2=new ArrayList<>();
    image3=new ArrayList<>();
    image4=new ArrayList<>();
    image5=new ArrayList<>();
    shop=new ArrayList<>();
    color=new ArrayList<>();
    stock=new ArrayList<>();
    material=new ArrayList<>();





    recyclerView=v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
//  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    String url = "-------------------MY-----API-----------------------";
    StringRequest sr= new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("result");



                for(int i =0;i<ja.length();i++)
                {

                    JSONObject jo1 = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    String ID=jo1.getString("ID");
                    String NAME=jo1.getString("NAME");
                    String BRAND=jo1.getString("BRAND");
                    String GENDER=jo1.getString("GENDER");
                    String DISCOUNT=jo1.getString("DISCOUNT");
                    String DESC=jo1.getString("DESCRIPTION");
                    String SELLPRICE=jo1.getString("SELLPRICE");
                    String MARKPRICE=jo1.getString("MARKPRICE");
                    String RATING=jo1.getString("RATING");
                    String TYPE=jo1.getString("TYPE");
                    String SIZE=jo1.getString("SIZE");
                    String CATEGORY=jo1.getString("CATEGORY");
                    String LENGTH=jo1.getString("LENGTH");
                    String IMAGE1=jo1.getString("IMAGE1");
                    String IMAGE2=jo1.getString("IMAGE2");
                    String IMAGE3=jo1.getString("IMAGE3");
                    String IMAGE4=jo1.getString("IMAGE4");
                    String IMAGE5=jo1.getString("IMAGE5");
                    String SHOP=jo1.getString("SHOP");
                    String COLOR=jo1.getString("COLOR");
                    String STOCK=jo1.getString("STOCK");
                    String MATERIAL=jo1.getString("MATERIAL");





                    id1.add(ID);
                    name.add(NAME);
                    brand.add(BRAND);
                    gender.add(GENDER);
                    discount.add(DISCOUNT);
                    desc.add(DESC);
                    sellprice.add(SELLPRICE);
                    markprice.add(MARKPRICE);
                    rating.add(RATING);
                    type.add(TYPE);
                    size.add(SIZE);
                    category.add(CATEGORY);
                    length.add(LENGTH);
                    image1.add(IMAGE1);
                    image2.add(IMAGE2);
                    image3.add(IMAGE3);
                    image4.add(IMAGE4);
                    image5.add(IMAGE5);
                    shop.add(SHOP);
                    color.add(COLOR);
                    stock.add(STOCK);
                    material.add(MATERIAL);


                }
                Log.d("abcde",id1.get(0));

                progressBar.clearAnimation();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),id1,name,brand,gender,discount,desc,sellprice,markprice,
                    rating,type,size,category,length,image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,shop,color,stock,material));





        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            progressBar.clearAnimation();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please check your internet connection...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    rq.add(sr);
    return v;
}
}
```

I am receiving each element of JSONArray in an ArrayList and then passing the ArrayList in recyclerView.

The question is if I reload this fragment this should show the updated data in database but it is not happening

Comment: i stopped reading when i saw all of your array lists. why are you doing this? you need to make a MODEL of items, and each item would habe an id, name, brand, gender, etc etc. then u just add those objets to ONE array list. the way you are doing it is completely wrong..... however, to reflect new data, you would do a notifyDataSetChanged() on the recyclerview

Comment: you would do a call to the DB again, either by refresh or other means, thatll refresh/update/remove/add the arraylist and THEN you would do the notifyDataSetChange()

Comment: What will be there in the model class??

Comment: There are plenty of examples of constructors with setters and getters. These are model classes. You then will have a List<ModelClass> instead of a List<String>. List.add(new ModelClass(...)) For example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution... The problem was that i was using Volley library which has a feature of caching enable by default.... So whenever I updated my database things were not reflected on the UI because of the cache that was saved  for that particular API... So every time i had to clear the app cache to see the changes from database...

The solution is before adding the StringRequest to RequestQueue disable the caching feature by using the function of StringRequest class

sr.setShouldCache(false) ;
rq.add(sr) ;

where sr and rq are the objects of StringRequest and RequestQueue classes...